# MySQL - How do I achieve my desired output with LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

The following query:

```
   SELECT friendship.dom, friendship.sub,
          user.id, user.fname, user.lname
     FROM friendship
LEFT JOIN user ON friendship.dom = user.id
```

results in the following:

```
dom  sub  id  fname  lname 
---------------------------
2    1    2   Seun   Soti
1    2    1   Donal  Lynch
```

But how do I make the output look like:

```
dom  sub  id_dom  fname_dom  lname_dom  id_sub  fname_sub  lname_sub
----------------------------------------------------------------------
2    1    2       Seun       Soti       1       Donal      Lynch
1    2    1       Donal      Lynch      2       Seun       Soti
```

I just need both users (`dom` and `sub`) to be included in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT 
  f.dom, f.sub,
  d.id dom_id, d.fname dom_fname, d.lname dom_lname,
  s.id sub_id, s.fname sub_fname, s.lname sub_lname
FROM friendship f
LEFT JOIN user d ON f.dom = d.id
LEFT JOIN user s ON f.sub = s.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT friendship.dom, friendship.sub, user.id AS id_dom, ...
FROM friendship
LEFT JOIN user ON friendship.dom = user.id
```

That should work for you. HTH

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT friendship.dom, friendship.sub,
      user.id, user.fname, user.lname,
      u1.id, u1.fname, u1.lname
 FROM friendship 
 FROM friendship
 LEFT JOIN user ON friendship.dom = user.id 
 LEFT JOIN user as u1 ON friendship.sub = u1.id
```